# change the 'container grid' of an elements in xaml ( VisualState )

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

i'm Using C# for Windows Store App.
I have a "MediaElement" inside a "Grid" in my **FullScreenPortrait** Page.
Now! i want to change the position of my "MediaElement" to position it in an other "Grid" when the app switches to **Snapped Mode** .
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
[YourGridName].Children.Remove([YourMediaElement]);
[YourOtherGridName].Children.Add([YourMediaElement]);
```

Might be easier to have one Grid with multiple columns and/or rows then you can move elements easily using

```
Grid.SetColumn([YourMediaElement], [Column number]);
Grid.SetRow([YourMediaElement], [Column number]);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Do you have an example?